# How to insert row with attributes using table.insertRow?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, format, row

I have a html table and insert a new row with `table.insertRow()`, but the new row doesn't have any attributes or formatting applied.  How can I add a row to the table with row formatting?

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />

<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />

<TABLE id="dataTable" width="100%" align="center">
    <TR align="center" border="1">
        <TH></TH>
        <TH>ID </TH>
        <TH>Name</TH>
        <TH>Status</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR align="center">
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD> 1 </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="text" value="Submission 1" /> </TD>
    <TD>Working version</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);

    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it's better to use jquery to add rows to tables

```
        $('#dataTable tr:last').after('<TR align="center"><TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD><TD>'+ rowCount + '</TD><TD> <INPUT type="text" value="Submission 1" /> </TD><TD>Working version</TD></TR>');
```

Answer (score 2):

To set the class name for a tablerow you simply need to edit the className attribute as done below

```html
<script>
var table = document.getElementById("tableID");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);
row.className = "rowdiv";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering insertRow() is usually where you put the index, and var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); is used here, how can you move it to specific part of the table?